# How to access array element by x:Static in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I had try the following, but got syntax error.

```cs
class A {
    public static int[] Numbers { get; } = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static A.Numbers[0]}" />  <!-- syntax error -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"x:Static" only supports accessing members of the type.
See the documentation: [StaticExtension Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.staticextension?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

To use a path (and the index is part of the path) you need a binding.
An example of such a binding:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [0], Source={x:Static lib:A.Numbers}}" />
```

Where `lib:` is the prefix associated with the namespace in which class A resides.

Or use a more modern binding syntax (since WPF 4.5):

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding (lib:A.Numbers)[0]}" />
```

**P.S.** Also, to eliminate possible errors, you should change the implementation of the Numbers property - protect the collection from change or make it observable.
Example:

```cs
    public class A
    {
        public static ReadOnlyCollection<int> Numbers { get; } = Array.AsReadOnly(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        // Or
        public static ObservableCollection<int> Numbers { get; } = new ObservableCollection<int> () { 1, 2, 3 };
    }
```

Comment: @Clements , `"{Binding (lib:A.Numbers)[0]}"` works for me in runtime, but doesn't work in Design Mode. Returns an empty value. Does this expression in Design Mode work correctly for you?